# popup is not coming in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

**index.html: this is the html**

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<title>shruthi reddy</title>


 <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript">window.NRUM ||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(e,t...</script>-->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Controller">
<h1> ASHOK KUMAR PETLA</h1>
<P>VIJAYAWADA IS KING IS VANGAVEETI MOHAN RANGA. </P>
<button type="submit" ng-click="create()">swathi</button>
<button type="submit" ng-click="subject()">srisha</button>
<button type="submit" ng-click="delete()">ramya</button>
<button type="submit" ng-click="edit()">sunitha</button>
</body>
</html>
```

APP.JS: ui bootstrap in js file . u can send the correct answer or code. i have tried but not come the popup.

**this is script of index.html**

```
var app=angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('Controller',['$scope', '$modal',function($scope,$modal){
    $scope.create=function(){
        var modalInstance=$modal.open({
            templateUrl:'views/prakash.html',
        });
    }

}]);
```

`index.html` and `app.js` .
pop up is not coming if the `swathi` is clicked.

Comment: Can you share code in plunckr or jsfiddle?

Comment: Open your console, and read the error messages. Your app depends on the ui.bootstrap module, but you don't have any script loading angular-ui-bootstrap in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the templateUrl you have given that is correct or the html file is available?

Or make sure you have initialized all the required dependent modules like `ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js`

I have created a plunkr for your code and that is working.

```
var app=angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('Controller',['$scope', '$modal',function($scope,$modal){
    $scope.create=function(){
        var modalInstance=$modal.open({
            templateUrl:'mypage.html',
        });
    }

}]);
```

See the plunkr here-

http://plnkr.co/edit/GRgjv8fyquOQirXwWaWQ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the -tpls.js file aswell, that file will make your own templates go into $templates.cache so you can use your own.

I can't see that you've installed the tpls file.

Also shouldn't it be `$uibModal` instead of `$modal`?
like so

```
var app=angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('Controller',['$scope', '$uibModal', function($scope, $uibModal) {
  $scope.create=function(){
    var modalInstance=$modal.open({
        templateUrl:'views/prakash.html',
    });
  }
}]);
```